# How to add hours and mins with a time in sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

how to add hours , minutes amd secs in same function in sybase..

```
SELECT dateadd(hh,3,getdate()
```

in this i need to add 3.5 [3hrs,30mins]. How to do that? can any one help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you add 210 minutes instead?

More specifically, convert to the smallest unit, and add that.  You can't add fractions of units.

Comment: Yes i can do like that.. thanks Hobo and HopKinson.. i convert the hours into mins and add.. Thnak you very much

Answer (score 2):

For some people, a more legible way would be:

```
SELECT dateadd(mi,30,dateadd(hh,3,getdate()))
```